# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in user control from another project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, nullreferenceexception, multiple-projects

I have a solution with 2 projects in it. One project(*TestControl*) contains the aspx file. then the other(*Controls*) for the usercontrols. I have already made it possible for the aspx to display the user controls via referencing the *Controls* in the project and copying the files to the *TestControl* Project. But the Sub seems not to work and it sends an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" even at a simple response.redirect code. I tried a msgbox and it works and also placing the code in page_load. But inside a sub it's not working. Any ideas why? and a fix?

Simple code in the uc3.ascx file

```
   Public Sub Redirect()

        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com")
    End Sub
```

Here is the error exception

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Web
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.UI.UserControl.get_Response()
       at Controls.uc3.Redirect() in C:\Users\Nelbin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestApp\Controls\uc3.ascx.vb:line 9
       at Controls.uc1.btnUserControl3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Nelbin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestApp\Controls\uc1.ascx.vb:line 16
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Paste the code to be helped please ;)

Comment: pasted the simple response.redirect. and the nullreference ex too :)

Comment: @JohnSaunders btw I checked your question/answer it seems I have nothing to match with those. I am not sure why its returning a null because in the breakpoint it has data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reason which I don't see from your code the control does not access `Response` object. Try

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response
```

intead of just `Response`.

```
Public Sub Redirect()
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com")
End Sub
```

In web project `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` should never be nothing.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Now my problem is still the same regarding with passing value from a user control to another

Comment: @HalimbawaDokumento: notice that this is definitely discussed in my Q&A: `Response` was null. Next step is to find out why, but first step was to find out what was null.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I saw that in your thread but can't think of a way to prevent that its null. Sorry I'm a noob haha. Now my next problem is regarding the value being pass on the user control to another. The control I believe is not initiated for no reason >.<

Comment: @HalimbawaDokumento: use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response` instead

Comment: could you give an example? I am getting the value via property or sub I don't know how can I use that part :(